# Which is the best practice in identical Cucumberjs definitions for a state (Given) and an outcome (Then), in Cypress?

Tags: typescript, cucumber, cypress, cucumberjs, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Having some doubt on best practices using `Cucumber.js` and `Cypress` for some step definitions.

Basically the test needs a state and an outcome that could be identically implemented:

This is the example of a state:

```
Given(
  'the {int} item of the {string} component is visible',
  (index, ComponentIndex, mapper: ComponentMapper) => {
    cy.get('[data-test^="cmp-"]').eq(cmpMap[mapper]).as(mapper)
    cy.get(`@${mapper}`)
      .find('.component__item')
      .eq(index)
      .should('be.visible')
  }
)
```

And this is the example of an outcome:

```
Then(
  'the {int} item of the {string} component is visible',
  (index, ComponentIndex, mapper: ComponentMapper) => {
    cy.get('[data-test^="cmp-"]').eq(cmpMap[mapper]).as(mapper)
    cy.get(`@${mapper}`)
      .find('.component__item')
      .eq(index)
      .should('be.visible')
  }
)
```

In this situation I see just code repetition, because the `Given` and the `Then` implements the same code, doing the same check. I would like to understand all possible solutions to implement this in the most efficient way.

#### DOUBLE IMPLEMENTATION

to leave the double steps defined as in the description
PRO: clearer
CONS: double code\

#### SINGLE IMPLEMENTATION

to leave one implementation, in the `Given` or in the `Then`, because cucumber actually does not check the match of the Step in the feature file and the function related to the step in the definition file
PRO: single implementation of code
CONS: less clear and more confusion in the step definitions

#### EXTERNAL FUNCTION

to create a function to put for example in some Commands of Cypress, or utils, and use it in both definitions
PRO: single implementation
CONS: over engineered? never saw this approach in Cucumber.js

Checking them all, which one would you suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more option, which is basically "Single implementation", but is a little more clear. I assume that you are using `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`, besides `Given`/`When`/`Then`, you can also import `defineStep` which does exactly same thing, but from code perspective its more clear that step defined this way is universal.

```
import { defineStep } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";

defineStep('the {int} item of the {string} component is visible', 
    (index, ComponentIndex, mapper: ComponentMapper) => {
    ...
});
```